# How wide must aerial roadways be for safe, fuel-efficient flying cars?

Tags: engineering, flying-machines, augmented-reality

[image]A dramatic scene in my story requires a pursuit with a vehicle “threading the needle” in flight between some structures. I need to describe how small that hole would be in relation to a typical roadway. This question establishes the “typical” roadway for flying cars.

First these are not aircraft but ground effect vehicles. While Star Trek, Star Wars, Blade Runner, The Jetsons, and every scifi I can think of has "magically hovering" private transportation, I am trying to design a *more* reality-based highway system for the flying cars in my world. A [rudimentary version of these cars exist today](https://youtu.be/gS-aQ1kCfV8?si=Spsx8nKAiOuF_Hlq), I am merely needing road engineering for these smaller, more maneuverable vehicles working in open “road” traffic.

Ground Effect Vehicle Highway System should accommodate the following elements:

- Ground effect vehicles (GEVs) are used instead of true aircraft.
- A typical vehicle would be extended to 10 feet width for flight and have a body height of 5 feet, running up to 15 feet in length. This is the area it presents to gusts/turbulence. It’s loaded mass is typically 2,500 lbs.
- The GEVs are powered by hydrogen fuel cells with a limited energy density.
- The GEVs cruise in ground effect between 2-5 meters over a surface, reducing drag and increasing efficiency.
- The GEVs normally travel at a speed of 160 kph (100 mph) and can maneuver through 0.8G turns at that speed via RAM air ducting and dynamic body control surfaces, at a cost to fuel economy if speed is to be maintained.
- The GEVs fly on a continuous route that is made up of any flat surface such as canals, open water, or grassy fairways.
  Passing lanes are vertical. They drive as normal cars otherwise.
- Drivers are not left to their own judgement at intersections: collision avoidance assisted by the road itself means only deliberate effort could cause a collision at intersections.
- Assume the system has been advanced to eliminate the possibility of two cars colliding mid-air at intersections, and also that collision avoidance systems can evade potential collisions when any car approaches without autonomous navigation (detailed below).
- Clear rules of the road determine what lane you can be in for any given situation (detailed below).

Here is a more detailed explanation of the highway design:

### These are NOT aircraft

Principles of aircraft, which generate aerodynamic lift with their plane surfaces, do not apply to air cushion vehicles. While both vehicles rely of a pressure differential across their horizontal control surfaces; the aircraft reduces pressure above the plane, while the air cushion craft increases the pressure beneath the plane. [Please watch this RC PAR ekranoplan in free flight and GE flight.](https://youtu.be/JY3PgBXeV9Y?si=Q0EO1U1a012a5tUV) Note that it is unstable in the air, but when it returns to GE altitude it immediately stabilizes on the air cushion. Therefore, please avoid answers relating to flight principles of aircraft. Turning, stalling, and most other dynamics of open air flight do not work the same for these vehicles. A high pressure cushion is actively created below the craft, so it can not bank or stall while in ground effect. Therefore **assume the engineering challenges of turning and maneuvering at speed have been resolved, and controlled free-air flight is possible at an enormous efficiency cost** A Computer rapidly adjusts control surfaces and ducts to hold stabile free-air flight.

### Efficiency

The GEVs are designed to be more efficient than traditional aircraft, and this is at the heart of this question. They fly in ground effect, which is the area of airspace that is affected by the surface below the vehicle. This reduces the drag on the vehicle's underside, which allows it to fly more efficiently. The GEVs cannot travel as far as a traditional aircraft on a single tank of fuel and every maneuver costs fuel. The highways are therefore designed to allow vehicles free flight with minimal maneuvering. The system also does not need the cars make costly stop and starts at intersections.

**This question only concerns a design for a GEV highway system.** In urban streets or irregular terrain the vehicles operate on the ground as regular cars. [Click here for a video of the cars I designed](https://photos.app.goo.gl/7eT9XQRYwPDf3rMe8) during a typical GE flight. Note that this is **not urban traffic**, it's a highway system which simply expands the suburban area around a business center, like the American Interstate system.  Even with the average car boasting 800 BHP, the LH2 economy in this world lacks the energy density to give everyone their own personal aircraft. This is why [vertical lanes are not possible](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/designing-a-traffic-system-for-flying-cars/109338#109338).

### Intersections

Intersections are handled the way we currently handle passing situations, by a brief acceleration to overcome the obstacle. My vehicles lift up and enter free space at intersections for brief periods at a large fuel expense.

[image: Intersection]
*(A typical intersection)*

There is of course a complete civil engineering task to fully design traffic flow in this scenario but assume that is accomplished, and please refer to the **items outside the scope of this question** at the bottom. I'm focusing narrowly on horizontal lane separation given that only real-world aerodynamic forces are maneuvering the vehicles. Here is the jist of the how highway system works:

- Roads are not rigidly constructed, they are augmented reality overlays in the driver's field of view. Except for basic emergency markers, all traffic signals, lane indicators, signs, and even commercial billboards are augmented reality overlays on your viewscreen.

[image: Driver view with AR overlay of road and advertising]

- Drivers will never need to compensate for normal wind gusts. "Smart Roads" provide active air movement data to vehicles. If a cross current is detected the road sends the "set and drift" data to approaching cars, which anticipate and auto-correct for most gusts up to 45 mph cross-winds. Obviously the effectiveness diminishes at low speeds, so for this question assume traffic travels at the speed limit.
- Drivers never “swerve.” Smart roads dynamically adjust their own lanes based on road conditions, such as an accident vehicle or passing ship. If your path will be obstructed for any reason such as an accident or passing ship, your display will project a "hill" ahead and your car simply jumps over the obstruction. Proximity sensors prevent tailgating, so cars can never be surprised.
- The car fully controls yaw to place the car on the smart road, ascending or descending as needed. Drivers work in two dimensions only. The feel of driving the vehicle is much like a car, with a slight addition of pitch and roll in turbulent air. The road determines their correct altitude until they go "off roading".
- Exiting the highway is done by pulling out of the main lane of traffic, decelerating, and banking away onto another "road" or off-road area.
- Cars are smart, but not fully automated. They have proximity-based cruise control, predictive gust correction, and lane-drift correction. Mostly however, the driver determines the lane and speed.
- There is no commercial freight on this highway but the highway will cross marine freight lanes and other obstacles occasionally. This again is handled by hopping the road over the obstacle in a virtual bridge. Again, cars automatically follow the road and there are no surprises.
- Turns are no less than 250m inside radius and speed limits reduce to 80mph. (This is a correction - originally wrote “diameter”)
- There is no anti-gravity anything. They rely on Power-Augmented RAM for lift and real-world aerodynamics.
- They can use air cushion hovering over water, wheels otherwise.
  [image]
  [image: Vehicle concept in GE flight]

(These pictures are concept art for reference, not a final design)

I do expect the vehicles to still be "road legal", meaning they are no more than 8 feet wide on ground, 10 feet max with extensible wings. They have very basic wheels which can brake and provide urban/neighborhood propulsion.

Today physical road lanes are officially exactly 11 feet wide, for a maximum legal vehicle width of 8 feet.

With consideration for minimizing correction maneuvers:
**If I were to visualize traffic in this type of highway, what would be the normal lane separation on this highway?**

An answer addresses how close we can be to oncoming traffic without disruptive turbulence, and to passing traffic in a lane to either side. I need the highway as narrow as possible without creating an excessive need for correctional maneuvers when other cars interract.

**Vehicle performance** will be much like the vehicle in [this patent](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5105898.html), however thrust and yaw can be used to decelerate the car at 0.6g on the road, but not at all in free flight where obstacles need to be handled as a plane would.

---

**Items outside the scope of the question**

I am only looking at lane separation for this specific road. As I describe driving on this highway in the story, what does it look like? The following other related engineering problems will be handled elsewhere:

- Traffic queuing for entering and exiting vehicles
- Aircraft
- Left-hand turns
- Vehicle technical specifications not already included
- Urban (low speed) travel
- Smart road fundamentals of operation
- Weather other than winds (precipitation, temperature, etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101054/discussion-on-question-by-vogon-poet-horizontal-lane-separation-for-flying-cars).

Comment: I added some stuff to chat.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't everything automated? You've already delegated so much to the computer. Positioning of other cars, dangers, how the road should be at that particular time thanks to weather. Automation seems a logical step from there. Just fill in your destination and your car does the rest. Safe speeds, the best road, to even parking spaces. You can have 0 separation and have it as safe as it will ever be.

Comment: @Trioxidane For the reasons explained, as well as the reasons full automation (FA)  isn’t on public roads today. FA [has been possible since 1960](https://www.autoevolution.com/news/the-story-of-the-gm-firebird-iv-the-1960s-autonomous-car-with-a-fridge-and-tv-180881.html) and FA UAV’s serve military missions, yet we don’t even fully automate freight trains. Humans won’t buy them, 90%+ of us need control. They would also be a huge national security risk - a good hacker can shut down the country or kill thousands of people. A fully autonomous public road just isn’t believable.

Comment: @VogonPoet automation on railways is actually decently common. A lot of metro systems are fully automated nowadays, & almost all new ones built are. Freight is less common but a railway in the pilbara has it's entire fleet of 100s of locomotives automated now.

Comment: @OT-64SKOT I would be surprised if a deep dive didn’t reveal that automated lines have very limited interaction with public vias; ie, they never have to make decisions involving human-guided vehicles. Likewise, to find automated services don’t employ a driver “just in case.” Automated closed tram systems are common at airports;  there are no decisions to make. However, fully automating complex public vias I think are a long way off technologically, further still as normative, and completely out of reach legally.

Comment: @OT-64SKOT Caveat to the above: When transportation exceeds human reaction time automation will become necessary, so we will have to choose between having the convenience of speed or the control. This may drive full automation as demand for rapid transit overcomes demand for control. That may well play in here as these vehicles could pack into narrower vias, and access more locations. Food for thought…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that might be a useful reference is to consider military helicopter separation distance. Because they regularly fly together very close to the ground in dangerous environments, it could give a baseline as to safety. While military pilots like this are certainly better trained than the average driver, you could argue that automation and augmented reality factors probably counter this enough.

What I found, for the example of [attack and reconnaissance helicopters](https://fas.org/irp/doddir/army/fm3-04-126.pdf), was a distance range of 3-5 rotor distances for close formation and a stagger distance of 150 meters(500 ft). While your craft obviously don't have rotors, you could consider their width as a reasonable enough substitute. This would give a minimum distance of at least 9 meters(30 ft) and a safer distance of around 15 meters(50 ft). **Lanes would then be between 12 meters(40 ft)and 18 meters(60 ft) wide(adding the size of the vehicle and giving half the separation distance on each side).**

I'm also concurring with the dissenting opinions that this would never work for all of the reasons indicated, but hopefully this helps regardless.

Also, those jumping intersections look suicidal. What happens when the automated system loses power. While traffic light failures are a major annoyance and lead to significant delays, they don't lead to guaranteed pileups at 100 mph.

Comment: Intersection worries: “pile-ups” just can’t happen when the vehicles are in 3-dimensional space (because things naturally fall down). The number of flying cars loosing power during an overpass would likely resemble the number of well-maintained cars loosing power going over bridges today. Assuming that eventually it will happen, and given vehicles will have a predictable momentum, a proper virtual road can align itself slightly left of right to ensure crossing traffic is “woven” together such that IF a car looses altitude mid-passage it will pass between crossing vehicles.

Comment: But what happens when they fail? That is the problem I don't think you're realizing. It's all well and good to talk about how it will work, but what will happen when it doesn't work exactly as you intend? Most engineering disasters can be traced to this style of thinking.

Comment: If the smart road fails at an intersection then the speed limit obviously has to reduce and everyone wastes gas idling along for a while. It would become a traffic cop situation and every car that just lost its road condition feed will alert the driver, which will require by law that they slow down. But yes, if a traffic control blinks out it would become as messy and dangerous as the paved intersections we all love, and someone might crash in those first few moments that the “red light” goes dark. I didn’t solve traffic jams and don’t think I can.

Answer (score 16):

## You're all going to die

There's a saying that applies to GEVs/WIGs as much as it does to hovercraft. If you can see something in front of you you're going to hit it. GEVs are not suitable for traffic situations, as they require a minimum speed rather than a maximum. They're not really suitable for use over land due to the fact they corner like aircraft and as such the inside 'wing' often hits the water. In the case of being over land the inside wing hits the ground and results in something referred to as 'a crash' apparently this is 'bad'.

Basically the way you've designed your transport system, if there's anything resembling traffic at an intersection, everybody dies.

But in terms of your actual questions, we come back to that old, "if you can see it you're going to hit it" problem. Without ground traction you don't have precise maneuvering, without precise maneuvering you must have really wide lanes and be a very long way from oncoming traffic. Possibly in the range of hundreds of meters.

You have no brakes. You have terrible steering. We could consider this equivalent to an icy road and take the 8 second guidelines for safe distances. However the level of automation added to these vehicles means I'd suggest 4 second following distance, 2 second lane width and 2 second vertical distance. For oncoming I'd suggest 4 seconds each way to collision point.

Option 2 is to not allow personal flying transport before full automation.

Comment: If this answer is OK with fully automated ground effect flying cars, then it should be OK with the ground effect flying cars concept? Are you assuming cars slow or stop at an intersection? I can’t tell. That’s not how intersections work. Highways we have today also have a speed minimum, this obviously has that concept carried over. The difference I think you didn’t consider is the fact that our cars can’t go over obstacles while these vehicles can, collision avoidance has a new dimension. Also I have no wings, nothing to touch the ground in banking, but an extendible skirt for slow travel.

Comment: @VogonPoet, I live in the UK, traffic can grind to a halt anywhere on any road at any time, there is always a slowing around intersections. The speed minimum is an open road thing, it's more a guideline for practical reasons, for a GEV it's a hard minimum to remain airbourne. You have a lifting body, but cornering still requires roll, that's going to bring you perilously close to the ground while under ground effect. 'Wings' is a useful term to cover the width you need in that body. Without larger wings you have very limited "over" available, both height and duration.

Comment: The trouble is that people on average are barely competent with ground vehicles, you're adding massive complications and crosswinds.

Comment: Your last paragraph at least addresses the question but is there any way to put some reasonable number on the lanes, considering there will be a minimum speed limit (to maintain control) and that vertical space can be used for collision avoidance (which will be automated, as stated in the question)? The concept of “swerving” to avoid an obstacle is gone, the car’s proximity sensors used in cruise control just pull up like automatic braking does today.

Comment: I am adding complications as well as modern collision avoidance, lane sensing, wind correction, and proximity sensing. As the question states, the driver only picks a lane and speed within safe parameters. No different from modern cars which won’t let you smash into the car in front of you, or lock up the brakes, or drift out of your lane.

Comment: @VogonPoet, give them 2 seconds gap lateral and vertical, 4 seconds following distance and you might be ok.

Comment: One of the major problems is not having brakes at all rather than worrying about them locking up.

Comment: Your answer understands that it is impossible to be surprised by a crosswind, right? The road knows what airflow is crossing it at all times, cars anticipate and autocorrect.

Comment: Your right it has no brakes, it has a vertical quasi-lane instead. Would it help if I describe how a crash scenario is handled in my question? I don’t want to invalidate your answer, so I’m asking.

Comment: @VogonPoet, I don't raise crosswinds because they're mostly only an issue on river crossings, you have allowed for them adequately. Crash scenarios are a matter for your world rather than a requirement for the question, but you must make allowances for the requirement to make an emergency stop. What happens when an airship crashes into the road for example. Up is not an option when the obstacle is coming down. Sometimes what you absolutely have to do is stop, and everyone has to be able to take account of that.

Comment: I think I’ve covered reasonably likely scenarios, I also think an airship crash-landing on our paved highways today were not factored into lane spacing so why would they become an issue here? This concern is very valid in a vertical lane separation scenario with true private air cars, but my vertical space is no different than how we use it today. I’m sorry if I didn’t make that clear. Maybe it is relevant to include more detail about collision avoidance as it will factor into a lane spacing decision. Can I add this please?

Comment: @VogonPoet, when it comes to flying cars, *everything* is about collision avoidance. An airship crashing doesn't factor now because the response is the same as for anything else, you stop, when you're airbourne, anything else airbourne is a major hazard, including pigeons. I'd leave as is for now and see what else comes along.

Comment: You also don't gain anything by using ground effect/air cuishion vehicles over land.  You still have to pave the roads, otherwise everything nearby gets blasted by flying dirt.  For instance, taking off from a dirt strip with a propellor plane, or the spray from even a small hovercraft over water: https://hovpod.com/surface-hovercraft/

Comment: As to turns, the vehicle does not rely on aerodynamic lift from control surfaces so the banking is not producing the turn. Power Augmented Ram technology uses ducts to vector thrust and change the vehicle’s angle of attack as well as its travel direction. Please do not rely to heavily on the concept art, which most certainly could not fly. Assume the engineering challenges of level turns have been overcome through dynamic vectoring and control surfaces.

Comment: @jamesqf The highways over land are grass, not bare dirt. At slow speeds on land they use wheels; air cushion can be used in water to lift off. None of this really relates to the question however. As to accidents, there will be periodic accident lanes like runaway truck ditches. That somewhat relates but the accident lanes are not continuous.

Comment: @Separatrix Crashes are addressed in the Q: Cars behind simply hop over it. Thins falling from the sky are handled the same way we handle them on the highway today. Grab the OS handle.

Comment: @VogonPoet, this is a blast from the past, you'll still want banking through the turns as that will greatly increase passenger comfort and load security, perfectly banked turns are a thing to be achieved as opposed to perfectly flat turns.

Comment: @Separatrix I considered it separate from the question as turn radius was “solved” in the details, but the wingtip argument I guess forces an explanation. I imagined a pivoting cockpit that rolled in turns, but a bank puts the air cushion at risk and would have to be done in free air. Instead the dynamic body and air ducting would provide lateral force. A complex maneuver handled by computer. Side gusts have a small sail area to work on & I don’t imagine them doing a lot of actual movement: 50kph over 2 seconds may nudge you a few meters. Without tunnel tests, has to be hand waved ATM.

Comment: (cont) Ekranoplans had to post spotters ahead of turns which were measured in miles, so I have no intention of making these rigid body vehicles. The assumption is that the technological obstacle has been overcome, as it’s certainly possible to generate 1-G lateral forces without friction given the right control surfaces and RAM air ducting. Not efficient at all however, hence the need to minimize these maneuvers by an  efficient road design. I will add size and mass to the question for calculations - these will be more dense than an airframe; so less susceptible to buffeting.

Comment: @VogonPoet, I can see you're putting a lot of detail into this, it may be better to create a new question for new considerations. I suggest you also look out for the tyranny of the rocket equation. The more complex you make the vehicle to overcome these obstacles, the larger and heavier it becomes, so it needs to be more powerful and hence again the larger and heavier it becomes. You'll potentially have to handwave a power source to get over some of these problems

Comment: @VogonPoet I should also add that 1-G lateral forces are achievable by modern cars under normal track conditions, that won't be enough for significant maneuvres at aircraft speeds.

Comment: I had 250m radius turns which works out to 0.8G @ 160kph. I reference a US highway turn should have an inner loop radius of 176m at 70mph according to FHWA. Upscale the speed and I pushed the turn out almost arbitrarily. Like our roads they aren’t really intended for significant maneuvers.

Comment: As to brakes that’s an evasion tactic for ground vehicles. With proper notice via a smart road a car can go over an obstacle, with the same economy cost cars suffer with excessive braking. But neither my scene nor this question relate to following distance; your recommendation will probably work when I need it.

Answer (score 6):

**It isn't going to work.**

Aircraft horizontal separation standards vary based on type of flying (uncontrolled, controlled, VFR, IFR, etc),  but is generally measured in miles, not feet.  For example, US ATC standards in a terminal area specify a minimum 3 nautical mile separation.  Even at Oshkosh during the fly-in they maintain separations of 1/2 mile for airplanes landing on the same runway.

In open airspace, separation requirements can be as high as five miles.

One of the main reasons for these large separations is that aircraft cannot manoever like ground craft, not being connected to a high friction surface.   If a vehicle breaks down or suddenly stops in front of you, you're going to need a lot more than 70m to stop if you are cruising at freeway speeds.

The other reason is that the air mass you are flying through is not steady, and the lift of the vehicle in front of you is going to throw off a lot of turbulence.

I know you hand-waved some kind of wind-change alert system, but that's not going to cut it.  It comes down to a simple matter of energy - it would be extremely hard to constantly counteract changing winds and turbulence in a way that kept your vehicle in a narrow 'lane'.   Even large jets can drop hundreds of feet in wind shear, and it doesn't take much crosswind to make them hard to land.

The logistical problems of many airborne craft trying to stay in densely packed lanes are immense.  Which is why we don't have flying cars now, and never will have them in large numbers over any city.  Keeping them in ground effect doesn't help and probably hurts, because it keeps those floating vehicles close to many obstacles.

Why do you need this?  If they can't stack vertically, just what are you gaining with ground effect vehicles?  Certainly not energy efficiency, as these vehicles have to expend power just to keep them off the ground.  Small hovercraft are lucky to get 5-10 mpg.

The only reason I can see for it is if somehow the ground can't be used.  Otherwise, tires are better.

Comment: To your question, have you looked at the efficiency gains of power-augmented ram vehicles? Energy efficiency is the primary reason. Traction irregularities and tire physical limitations are the next reason. Removing unpredictable road hazards is another (air is sloppy but predictable). Yes, one gain is traded off for another challenge. If the answer is “one mile” then that’s the answer, hoping it’s well referenced however.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_(aeronautics)

Comment: But this isn’t strictly aeronautics. That article needs to be dissected to find which factors are and are not relevant at 4 meters altitude. There is no vertical component - or it is trivial at least.

Comment: Vertical doesn't matter,   Look at it this way:  let's say you are in the middle of a 70m lane, and get hit with a 30 mph gust of wind from the side.  You are now moving laterally at 13 meters per second, and will be out of your lane in less than three seconds.   To prevent this, you would have to accelerate laterally from 0-30 mph in less than three seconds.   Good numbers for a sports car on a road, impossible numbers for a ground effects machine already expending most of its energy staying in the air.  And 30 mph is nothing.  Do the math for a 70 mph gust like you'd get in a microburst.

Comment: I am aware of these things and I though I said so in the question, the car will never be surprised and can correct for 45 mph gusts (those are actually quite rare at low levels outside a storm). I am working out the (heavy) lateral requirements separately - with many design considerations. For this problem, I'm just assuming those details have been solved and would like to know how to describe such a highway to an audience.

Comment: And to clarify, being notified that the wind is coming doesn't help much, other than that maybe you could move to the windward side of the lane to maximize the time you have to correct when the gust hits.  But you can't actually correct for the wind until you are in it, so if it comes on fast you WILL drift until you can counteract it.   Then there is turbulence generated from obstacles, wake turbulence from other vehicles, etc.   All this applies to anything that is not making physical contact with the ground, no matter how high it is.

Comment: Given your last comment, I have to ask how 'hard' your science is here,   Do you have some fanciful technology to power these things?   If not, I question the ability to any airborne vehicle to stay in a narrow lane in a wide range of weather conditions.  You can work out the energy required by thinking of maximum gusts you are willing to deal with, etc.    Also, is it possible for your vehicles to transition to a 'ground' mode with wheels when the weather is outside of your limits?

Comment: I deliberately left out the [tag:hard-science] tag for the known problems and self-confessed hand-waving. This also concerns me and this is relevant to the question. If compensating an anticipated gust requires shifting the lane, how far do I need to slide over? Also please remeber the lanes are actually virtual, so when a gust is known to be coming, the road can literally just move every lane over a couple meters, each car in every lane gets affected. Of course gusts are not instantaneous so it's more complicated, but not impossible? At some margin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101042/discussion-between-dan-hanson-and-vogon-poet).

Answer (score 1):

**If all the practical issues are dealt with as you say, I see no reason 'lane widths' would then emulate existing ones, however this is a missed opportunity**

One of the major complexities in modern day city / traffic / urban planning is that the 2 dimensional plane, the ground plane, contains:

- Roads and intersections
- Buildings
- Vegetation
- Rivers
- Complex topography, perhaps quite steep slopes and mountainous terrain
- residents with ownership of sky
- parks, with kids and drones and kite flyers
- industrial developments, with chimneys, noxious chemicals and exhaust
- sensitive areas, such as prisons, police and military installations

So there is a fair degree of complexity in laying this all out - without an overlay of free traffic over the top hovering just above the ground plane. Removal of transport from the ground plane will in some ways make things easier, and in others more challenging.

Lane width is perhaps one of the minor issues, but sure 3.5m is standard (in Australia anyway). The restrictive intersections you mention may perhaps also be a lost opportunity to get much more height, and make use of a true 3-dimensional city.

Privacy, security and practicality with regards to the above functions would be another question - but perhaps a great one to ask!

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what this is saying from the wording, am I right to assume you mean that full 3-dimensional roadways would be better? Also, you think 3.5m separation works at 160kph speeds? While most crosswinds won’t push a car out of its lane, the way to compensate for them (automatically) I assume must involve pitching the vehicle into the wind with the rudder and punching the thrust. This means cars can sometimes fly a bit cockeyed in crosswinds, so maybe lanes should consider this? How does flying parallel to another car this close (less than 1 meter) affect aerodynamic control?

Comment: My reason for avoiding full 3-d roadways is energy cost. I’m trying to leverage ground effect energy efficiencies. I’m hand waving the vehicle design parameters but want the aerodynamic factors fully considered in civil engineering the highway.

Comment: @VogonPoet ground effect doesn't mean you can't put actual bridges at intersections, or just lose a little  bit of energy efficiency for the short while you'll be airborne, even if the car doesn't have enough engine juice to achieve sustained flight

Comment: @JohnDvorak I could build bridges, or at least jump ramps, and eventually I might. For now I’m focused on an agile smart road that puts traffic flow priority before making cars fit the infrastructure. Energy cost of maneuvering millions of cars through rigid roads exceeds the cost of the road over time. In this world, the road adjusts to maximize the efficient delivery of traffic demand.